# Change component objects in powerapps

Tags: components, powerapps

I have a component library with component with a lblText field. I published the component and I'm able to include it in a power app. What I want to do is change the text property of lblText programmatically when the app is started. So far I have not been able to accomplish this.

I have tried various ways of addressing the field in the app and I have tried to make the default value in the component a variable that I could set in the app. No joy so far.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Carter

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The component in the component library is page header (1366x50) consisting of two text label fields, a title and a subtitle. I would like to be able to use the subtitle field as a placeholder and change it when it is imported to an app.